# Media Instagram Last month

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm creating this Instagram Integration and I'm using https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search endpoint.
I want to know if is possible to get all the medias for an specific month, with the min and max timestamp. 
I'm seeing on the documentation that The time span must not exceed 7 days.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you're willing to make multiple requests. They only give you a handful of media on each query so to get all the media from the last month you'll have to paginate your request, changing the "max_timestamp" to be the created_time from the oldest media you got on the previous request. You can keep going back in time until you've pulled everything from the last month.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the `min_timestamp` and `max_timestamp` to a month and make a request, you still have to make pagination calls to get all media.

Here is an implementation: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map
Set the time range and map location and search, scroll to load all media.